# Alignment issue in Mobile device (Responsive)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

By using the inspect element option from the browser I have identified which code needs to be updated to place the logo in the center. I have added text-align: center and it worked fine, so I have updated the same code in source to reflect the same. But it is not getting updated after adding in source code at the same time works fine while adding via the inspect element option. Please help me on how to achieve this

CSS code is added below for your reference

```
@media (max-width: 959px)
.menu-container .logo-container {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 27px 36px 27px 36px !important;
}
```

Comment: heyy add your full code with html

Comment: I think the code is being overridden by some code written after this code. Try inspecting again and see what code is being applied.

Comment: Site link, please.

Comment: http://checkmate.health/ @m4n0

Comment: You try to set logo in middle of what ?

Comment: I am trying to set the logo center instead of left for the mobile device

Comment: It is already centered on mobile: https://nimb.ws/xwFq3d It could be your cache.

Comment: No but it is working fine now because I have added source code in another theme file @m4n0 It is working fine now. Thank you for discussing me on this. THe same code working fine

Comment: I am trying to remove the sticky logo to scrollable. If you found any add your answer @m4n0 I am trying from my end. Thank you

Comment: Close this one and open a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code seems to be invalid. It should be like this:

```
@media (max-width: 959px) {
    .menu-container .logo-container {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        padding: 27px 36px 27px 36px !important;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I have removed the construct stylesheet, I did it is not working

Comment: Make sure you are viewing the website with viewport width below 959px and that you clear your browser cache. Otherwise, it might be the wrong selector (not `.menu-container .logo-container`) or specificity issue, which you can try solving by adding ` !important` after `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class like where it works fine:

```
@media (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px)
.menu-container .logo-container {
    text-align: center !important;
    float: none !important;
    position: relative !important;
    padding: 27px 36px 27px 36px !important;
}
```

Juste remove the  `and (min-width: 768px)` and you will have your result.

so it should be like (more or less you just need to add `float: none !important;`):

```
@media (max-width: 959px)
    .menu-container .logo-container {
        text-align: center !important;
        float: none !important;
        position: relative !important;
        padding: 27px 36px 27px 36px !important;
    }
```